# How to capture form values in wordpress admin

Tags: wordpress, forms

I am creating a plugin in which i am adding database values from frontend form submission(contact form7) and those values i am listing via wp_list_tables

above mentioned is happening perfectly

Now i an trying to update those values, so when i am clicking on edit function i am opening form via capturing id from $_GET and listing those vaules in form

But here i want to update those values and i am not sure how to perfrom this task to get form values ..i mean what action should i write here

below is my code

```
    public function booking_details_page(){

    $this->booking_id =  (int) $_GET['booking_id'];
    $bid = $this->booking_id;
    global $wpdb;
    $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM dF5Bt_taxi_booking WHERE booking_id ='$bid'" );
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
            <div id="icon-users" class="icon32"></div>
            <h2>Blacktaxi Booking Page</h2>
            <?php       
                foreach($myrows as $row) {
                    $booking_name = $row->booking_name;
                    $booking_email = $row->booking_email;
                    $booking_phone = $row->booking_phone;
                    $booking_from = $row->booking_from;
                    $booking_to = $row->booking_to;
                    $booking_date = $row->booking_date;
                    $booking_status = $row->booking_status;
                    $booking_car = $row->booking_car;
                    $booking_days = $row->booking_days;
                    $booking_night = $row->booking_night;
                    $booking_pickup_add = $row->booking_pickup_add;
                }
                    echo '<form method="POST" action="?page=blacktaxi-bookings.php&action=confirm">
                    <table>
                    <tr>
                    <td><label>Booking ID  : </label></td>
                    <td><input name ="booking_id" type="text" value="'.$bid.'" disabled></td>
                    <td><label>Customer Name  : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name ="booking_name" value="'.$booking_name.'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><label>Customer E-mail: </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name ="booking_email" value="'.$booking_email.'"></td>
                    <td><label>Customer Phone (+91): </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name ="booking_phone" value="'.$booking_phone.'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><label>Booking From   : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name ="booking_from" value="'.$booking_from.'" disabled></td>
                    <td><label>Booking To     : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name ="booking_to" value="'.$booking_to.'" disabled></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><label>Booking Date(yyyy-mm-dd): </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name ="booking_date" value="'.$booking_date.'"></td>
                    <td><label>Car Type       : </label></td>
                    <td><select name="cars">
                            <option value="'.$booking_car.'">'.$booking_car.'</option>
                            <option value="Sedan">Sedan</option>
                            <option value="Premium Sedan">Premium Sedan</option>
                            <option value="SUV">SUV</option>
                            <option value="Premium SUV">Premium SUV</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><label>Days           : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name ="booking_days" value="'.$booking_days.'"></td>
                    <td><label>Night          : </label></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name ="booking_night" value="'.$booking_night.'"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><label>Pick Up Address: </label></td>
                    <td><textarea name ="booking_pickup_add" class="widefat" cols="40" rows="3" value="'.$booking_pickup_add.'"></textarea></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Confirm Booking" class="button button-primary button-large" name="btn-confirm-booking"/></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    </tr>                       
                    </table>
                    </form>';
       ?> </div>
    <?php
}
}
```

See in form

```
<form method="POST" action="?page=blacktaxi-bookings.php&action=confirm">
```

i was trying to capture action but i am not able to get post form values if i am doing that.

can you help?

Comment: Try to change your form action to this `<form method="POST" action="blacktaxi-bookings.php?action=confirm">`

Answer (score 1):

You are posting data to a page, so you need to modify your action. `POST` and `GET` methods are similar but differ on how thy work. 
Change your code from this:

```
<form method="POST" action="?page=blacktaxi-bookings.php&action=confirm">
```

To this:

You can also set only the destination page for your action without the querystring and then set in your php page how the post action will be handled. For example:

```
<form method="POST" action="blacktaxi-bookings.php"> 

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'confirm'){
    // your code here
}
?>
```

NB: you need to pass the action param to the page, to achieve this you can use an hidden input field that will be posted with the form data:

```
<form method="POST" action="blacktaxi-bookings.php"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="confirm">
</form>
```